# SQLite3 object not understood?

Tags: c++, sqlite

Now I'm geting an error:

1>c:\development\document_manager\document_manager\storage_manager.h(7) : error C2079: 'storage_manager::db' uses undefined struct 'sqlite3'

with

```
 #pragma once
 #include "sqlite3.h"
class storage_manager
{
    sqlite3 db;
    sqlite3** db_pp;
public:
    void open()
    {
        sqlite3_open("data.db", db_pp);
    }
};
```

Old Question:
Hi everyone. I downloaded sqlite-amalgamation-3_6_13.zip from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html, but I'm not able to compile it in my project. I receive many errors like:

```
c:\pathtoproject\sqlite3.c(11337) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'
        Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast

c:\pathtoproject\sqlite3.c(12023) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'sqlite3_int64 *'
        Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast
```

What do I need to do to compile my project properly? Thanks!

Edit: 
    I don't want to compile the whole program as C, I just want to compile three files as c, is this possible?

EDIT: FIXED! I created an new project.

Comment: I don't want to compile the whole program as C, I just want to compile three files as c, is this possible?

Comment: Yes, check my answer. You can specify individual files to be compiled as C, it doesn't have to be project-wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be trying to compile a C program using a C++ compiler. While there is a lot of C code which is also valid C++, they are different languages.

Your compiler may have some switch or setting to compile C code. Check your compiler documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile the file as C code rather than C++.
Right click on either the project or just the .c file, and in properties, make sure it is set to compile as C, rather than C++. (You may want to set this setting just for the file, not the entire project)

Comment: The sqlite3.c file is already set to compile as C. What do I do?

Comment: I kind of expected that (it should be set to C by default for .c files), but it's strange. My VC2k8 compiles it just fine. You're not #including the .c file directly, are you?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the compiler tell you what to do? You need an explicit cast:

```
void *pv = /* some value */;
char *pc = (char*) pv;
```

This is of course not a problem in C, but an issue of C++.

Comment: I don't think I'd like to go through 15000+ lines of sqlite to add explicit casts, so how would  I make VC++ interpret the file as a c code file?

Comment: Goto Project Properties> C/C++ > Advanced > Compile As > Compile as C code.